# Save the progress from the game

Tags: android

I am making a some sort of game that will give the users some coins (let's say 10) for each game. I want to make sure when the user opens the app and play the game again, it should save the progress from the last game and continue after 10 coins but not 0 even when user has completely exited the app or app was crashed. Please guide me through this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check out [Data Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/index.html) in the Android API Guides.

Answer (score 3):

Well for minimal data you could use SharedPreferences. If you will be storing a decent amount of different variables it is best to use some sort of file whether it be a database or text file.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the android page describing different storage options http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

For a game you should probably use a SQLite database if you plan to store a decent amount of game state. If, however, you only want to store a few values, you could use the SharedPreferences options. Just remember to put and commit the new values whenever the player exits the app. Or if you want to make sure they still keep their coins after a crash, you could write the SharedPreferences values every time the coin value changes.